# Java Future always returning null

Tags: java, null, future

Hey I got a quick question about Java Futures. I broke down the problem to this snippet:

```
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    try {
        System.out.println(service.submit(new FutureTask<>(() -> true)).get());
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I expect this to output "true" on my terminal. But instead it always outputs null. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the `FutureTask` that's throwing off the logic.
Your `() -> true` is a `Callable<Boolean>` returning `true`, but `FutureTask` is a `Runnable` which doesn't return a value. Therefore `submit` returns a `Future<Void>` (since it's getting a `Runnable` parameter, not a `Callable`), which always contains null.

Remove the unnecessary `FutureTask` wrapper and just use the `Callable` directly.

Comment: Thanks, that is the problem.

Answer (score 4):

`FutureTask` extends `Runnable` interface

From java docs for `ExecutorService.submit(Runnable)` method:

> Submits a Runnable task for execution and returns a Future
> representing that task. The Future's {@code get} method will return
> {@code null} upon *successful* completion.

to get result you can use `Callable`:

```
System.out.println(service.submit(() -> true).get());
```

or get result from task:

```
FutureTask<Boolean> task = new FutureTask<>(() -> true);
service.submit(task);
System.out.println(task.get());
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `FutureTask`. If you call your service with `Callable` or `Runnable`, it works as expected and returns the result:

```
Future<?> result = service.submit(() -> true);

System.out.println(result.get()); // prints true
```